# Frequency of elements in a list of list

Tags: python, list, word-frequency

My goal is to count frequency of words in a list of list. So, I have:

```
list_1 = [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'w'], ['w', 'x', 'y']]
```

My goal is something like:

```
x:3, y:3, w:2, z:1
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(elem for sub in list_1 for elem in sub)
Counter({'x': 3, 'y': 3, 'w': 2, 'z': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
list_1 = [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['x', 'y', 'w'], ['w', 'x', 'y']]

freq = {}

for i in list_1:
    for j in i:
        try:
            freq[j] += 1
        except KeyError:
            freq[j] = 1
        
print(freq)
```

Comment: Thanks really much for your time and attention, Marko, I really appreciate it!!